# VSCode Not able to edit the code during runtime

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not able to edit my NodeJS code during the program run-time. HTML and client side JavaScript files are my main goals. Please let me know if there is edit and continue feature available in Visual Studio code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not yet implemented. But I have already heard requests for it, so you should vote for it here https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code

Comment: Feature request: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7769226-change-files-while-debugging